# Find function's arity in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, arity, parameter-list

I've been doing some Genetic Programming and I've been separating functions into different function sets based on their arity; it's all rather complex.

I'd like to know if there's a simpler way to to do it. For example, if there's a function that returns the arity of a given function.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: Seems to be implementation-dependent. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.lisp/0WoivuykcKM/0SnbqcFyNogJ

Comment: There's a very close portable library: https://github.com/Shinmera/trivial-arguments but it returns the full lambda list, not the arity.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For interpreted functions you should be able to use [`function-lambda-expression`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_fn_lam.htm).

For compiled functions, alas, this function often returns `nil`, so you will have to use an implementation-dependent function ([clocc](http://clocc.sourceforge.net/)/[port](http://sds.podval.org/data/port.html)/[sys.lisp](http://clocc.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/clocc/clocc/raw-file/tip/src/port/sys.lisp)):

```
(defun arglist (fn)
  "Return the signature of the function."
  #+allegro (excl:arglist fn)
  #+clisp (sys::arglist fn)
  #+(or cmu scl)
  (let ((f (coerce fn 'function)))
    (typecase f
      (STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION (pcl:generic-function-lambda-list f))
      (EVAL:INTERPRETED-FUNCTION (eval:interpreted-function-arglist f))
      (FUNCTION (values (read-from-string (kernel:%function-arglist f))))))
  #+cormanlisp (ccl:function-lambda-list
                (typecase fn (symbol (fdefinition fn)) (t fn)))
  #+gcl (let ((fn (etypecase fn
                    (symbol fn)
                    (function (si:compiled-function-name fn)))))
          (get fn 'si:debug))
  #+lispworks (lw:function-lambda-list fn)
  #+lucid (lcl:arglist fn)
  #+sbcl (sb-introspect:function-lambda-list fn)
  #-(or allegro clisp cmu cormanlisp gcl lispworks lucid sbcl scl)
  (error 'not-implemented :proc (list 'arglist fn)))
```

EDIT: note that *arity* in CL is not really a number, since Lisp functions can accept [*optional*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_dab.htm), [*rest*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_dac.htm) and [*keyword*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_dad.htm) arguments in addition to [*required*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_daa.htm) ones; this is why the above `arglist` function returns the [lambda list](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_d.htm) of the argument function, not a number.

If you are only interested in functions which accept only required parameters, you would need to use something like

```
(defun arity (fn)
  (let ((arglist (arglist fn)))
    (if (intersection arglist lambda-list-keywords)
        (error "~S lambda list ~S contains keywords" fn arglist)
        (length arglist))))
```

Comment: Thanks, I just discovered that I can call clisp's own #'arglist, then do a member search on the list it returns.

Comment: This is a great answer, but also check the answer below "trivial-arguments"! Super light library, you can simply call (arglist fn) easily and portably.

Comment: For [CCL](https://ccl.clozure.com) there is `ccl:arglist`, which should be added to the portable `arglist ` definition above (and ideally also at CLOCC).

Answer (score 1):

There is a portable library that gives the function's lambda list: https://github.com/Shinmera/trivial-arguments

```
(ql:quickload "trivial-arguments")
```

Example:

```
(arg:arglist #'gethash)
;; => (sb-impl::key hash-table &optional sb-impl::default)

(defun foo (a b c &optional d) nil)
(arglist #'foo)  ;; => (a b c &optional d)
```

It returns the full lambda list, with `&optional` and stuff, so we can't just get the `length` of the result for the arity.

Comment: Great library! Have been using it a lot for some portable meta-programming! Couldn't be easier to choose.